# Hide implementation details from developers in single assembly

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I want to decouple `Foo` from `FooHandler`. Also they should be registered by DI via assembly scanning. Therefore I have 3 types:

```
interface IFooHandler { // no type arguments, so it can be used by reflection
   void DoStuff(object foo); 
}

interface IFooHandler<TFoo>: IFooHandler { // TFoo tells us, what foo is it for
   void DoStuff(TFoo foo); // developers are happy with strongly typed foos
}

abstract class FooHandler<TFoo>: IFooHandler<TFoo> {
   void IFooHandler.DoStuff(object foo){
       DoStuff((TFoo)foo); // adapter of interface 2 to 1
   }
   abstract void DoStuff(TFoo foo); // for nice implementation
}
```

The problem with such design is that I cannot easly forbid other people in my assembly from using `IFooHandler` or `IFooHandler<TFoo>` directly. Using first is bad idea, because it will not be registered in DI and it will fail. Using second is bad idea, because you write useless boilerplate, already written in base class.

Is it reasonable, to add `Obsolete` attribute with `error=True` to prevent people from using these interfaces? Is there is better way to hide them (I cannot move them to another assembly and mark as internal).

Concrete example:
Lets say we have webapplication, and in that panel on various types there are contexts (Foo) that are identify of list of options for given context. Lets say you have currency selection, and Foo is `CurrencyList`. Then you have `CurrencyListProvider` class, that takes CurrencyList, retrieves available currencies from database and returns to panel, so user can choose which currency he want use for transaction. I am using concrete types, so you may easily move over codebase with tools such as resharper, but inside these concrete types there are string traveling through http.

Comment: I will be honest, it is really hard to give advice with things called `Foo` - since I struggle to visualise a use-case. A concrete example makes it easier for some people, like me, to give suggestions.

Comment: @mjwills Here You go. But question is about such designs in general, where You have stuff that consists from id and handler, and You want register handlers for type automatically and then retrieve them via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it reasonable, to add Obsolete attribute with error=True to prevent people from using these interfaces?

No. If you are afraid somebody will access your implementation directly, this won't stop them. A side effect is that they will question your skills as developer.

> Also they should be registered by DI via assembly scanning

This is where your pain lives. Assembly scanning is just that: check the assembly and create instances, preferably through a nice public constructor. So, if you don't drop this requirement it's going to be... too complicated.

If you where to drop this requirement, and I think you can, since you have 3 versions and need a mechanism to switch between them; consider to use a own factory.

Let your factory decide which version to return.

You could even use [friend assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/friend-assemblies) to protect the constructors.

**the real answer:**

---

Just make sure your documentation is complete. If people read that you discourage the use of a certain type, let them decide. If your assemblies are well documented it helps you:

- a) maintain your code through time
- b) to refer to the docs if somebody screws-up
- c) help your users correctly use your library

I think it's the only logical thing to do and much more descent than marking things as obsolete.

Comment: `won't stop them` - I do not want to have them stopped by all means, I just want them to be notified if for instance resharper suggests interface instead of base class and they accept. I agree, that documentation should be enough, but realistically there are deadlines and people who do not read docs, so I want to implement additional protection.

Comment: Assembly scanning is much nicer than explicit Factory, because IoC container is my Factory. It can instantiate type automatically with any constructor. `since you have 3 versions` - I want to have one version, just some dev can use internals on my mechanism to skip assembly scanning in same manner, as someone can implement class and not implement factory. I do not want friend assemblies or similar stuff.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of your IoC pattern; the thing is; because you let Unity or perhaps AutoFac deal with the instantiation you have - in general - little control over the creation of you objects. Nevertheless, if you really have 3 instances, you must have some sort of mechanism in place. With a lot of IoC containers you can have named registrations and default registrations. Maybe it's woth to dive into that subject.

Comment: maybe I specified it incorrectly. I have 3 interfaces, that someone can code aganist, but I want only one class (instance), that implements them(for each TFoo) all via my base class. If someone creates class that implements only first interface it won't register (so it's bad). If someone implements 2 or 3 it is ok. There are many implementations of `IFooHandler`, but only single implementation of `IFooHandler<TFoo>`, and everything is resolved by `IFooHandler<TFoo>`, so I don't need keyed registrations or custom factories.

Comment: Yes, I am not telling you you *need* a factory. It would just overcome the problems when instantiating the class. But; please answer this: you want users NOT to use certain INTERFACES, correct?

Comment: Yes (interfaces are used by my internals, and if I could afford separate assembly they would be internal in that assembly).

Comment: Ok, and those interface that are not to be used, could they be marked as `internal`? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, they are `internal`, but there are other developers that create stuff in that assembly, and they can use that `internal` interface if they don't read doc.

Comment: Ah.. now I get it XD .... I don't know of a pattern which can help you to not to use an internal interface within the same source code/assembly. You are aware of the XML documentation of visual studio I assume. Other than that i'm blank.

Comment: Ye, I documented it with xml doc, but someone may use autocomplete to implement wrong type. If it had obsolete attribute, he would be forced to ignore it, so I hope that he would inspect what he is trying to implement and read the doc.